# Nemo action doesn't work with comand that works in most file managers (as menu services/actions)

Tags: scripting, command, menu, file-manager, nemo

I have some commands that I use in many file managers in the same form.

Taking one as an example:

```
terminator -e  "filebot -get-subtitles -rename -non-strict %f"
```

In the same form it works in a Thunar custom action, and also  after  the `Exec=` line in a Nautilus action file in `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions` (that also appears in PCManFM), in a contract file in Pantheon-Files (`~/.local/share/contractor/`) and in a service-action file in Dolphin (`~/.local/share/kservices5/`).

Creating a `nemo_action` file in `~/.local/share/nemo/actions/` of the form

```
[Nemo Action]

Name=Download ENGLISH subtitles
Exec=terminator -e  "filebot -get-subtitles -rename -non-strict %f"
Selection=s
Extensions=avi;flv;mp4;mov;dir;
```

I get this error:

```
 /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

---

#### This is posted in order to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two more lines are needed for this to work:

```
Quote=double
EscapeSpaces=true
```

But also a change is needed in the command: instead of `%f` it must be `'%F'`.

So:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Download ENGLISH subtitles
Exec=terminator -e  "filebot -get-subtitles -rename -non-strict '%F'" 
Selection=s
Extensions=avi;flv;mp4;mov;dir;
Quote=double
EscapeSpaces=true
```

---

On problem with spaces some discussions [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/693) and [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/398).

On the `%F` token - [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action) - under `# Standard tokens that can be used`:

```
# %F - insert path list of selection
...
# %f or %N (deprecated) - insert display name of first selected file
```